# if anonymous, what is a call to python lambda?

Tags: python, lambda

I have lambda_expr ::= "lambda" [parameter_list]: expression

and you are supposed to be able to do this without assigning it to a name.  So what constitutes a call to a lambda function.  In other words, if you want to use this as an inline function, what makes it do what it is supposed to do?

Comment: I don't understand the question.  What constitutes a call to a lambda is the same as what constitutes a call to any other function.  Can you show an example of what you're asking about?

Comment: ahh you want to call lambda without giving it a name???

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A lambda expression returns a `function` object, so you call it the same as you would any other function, with `()`.

```
>>> (lambda x : x + 3)(5)
8
```

A more "normal"-looking function call works the same way, except the function object is referenced by name, rather than directly. The following demonstrate three different ways of accomplishing the same thing: calling a function that returns the value of its argument plus three.

```
def foo_by_statement(x):
    return x + 3

foo_by_expression = lambda x: x + 3

print foo_by_statement(2)
print foo_by_expression(2)
print (lambda x: x + 3)(2)
```

The first is the traditional way of binding a function object to a name, using the `def` statement. The second is an equivalent binding, using direct assignment to bind a name to the result of a `lambda` expression. The third is again calling the return value of a `lambda` expression directly without binding it to a name first.

Normally, you never actually write code like this. `lambda` expressions are most useful for generating function objects that are only needed as arguments to higher-order functions. Rather than having to define the function and bind it to a name you will never use again, you simply create the value and pass it immediately as an argument. For example:

```
plus_three = map(lambda x: x+3, [1,2,3])
```

Comment: lambda tutorials seem to always have examples like `foo_by_expression = lambda x: x + 3`. By assigning a name, the purpose of a lambda is pretty much gone. I'm not really griping about the answer but am hoping to highlight that one doesn't really do lambdas like that.

Comment: @tdelaney: Agreed; I hate those examples (and the misguided ideas people get from those examples, and the SO questions they lead to…); it's nice to see an explanation of when `lambda` actually _is_ useful. (Although in this case, `plus_three = (x+3 for x in [1, 2, 3])` might be better, and least the example isn't actively misguided.)

Comment: Agreed; it's just to highlight the fact that `def` statements and `lambda` expressions generate identical objects. Once the function object is bound to a name, you can't tell (and shouldn't care) how the name was bound.

Comment: @chepner: Except in introspection and debugging, of course. `foo_by_statement.__name__` is `'foo_by_statement'`; `foo_by_expression.__name__` is `'<lambda>'`. So the `repr`, the output in a traceback, etc. are all going to be a lot more useful for the former.

Answer (score 2):

When you define a function, python creates a function object and assigns it to a name. When you define a lambda, python creates a function object but doesn't assign it to a name. This is useful in several situations but a common use case is when you want to do a small conversion but don't want to bother with writing a regular function (and having to decide what to name it). Suppose I want to take the power of some numbers, I can

```
>>> for num in map(lambda i,j: i**j, range(10), range(10)):
...     print num
... 
1
1
4
27
256
3125
46656
823543
16777216
387420489
```

Here, map takes a function and calls it with a sequence of parameters.

Comment: Nice example of a case where a comprehension might not be better (because then it would require `zip`). Examples that don't use `map` in the first place, like a `tkinter.Button` callback or a `threading.Thread` target, may be simpler, but it's hard to think of one that doesn't require knowledge in some area that novices might not have. (Also, many of the typical examples for those cases are best written with `partial` anyway…)